# Which starts first ? BootExecute or PendingFileRenameOperations?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

There are some keys in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager, including
**BootExecute** and **PendingFileRenameOperations**.
Which starts first ? BootExecute or PendingFileRenameOperations ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a Sysinternals Process Monitor bootlog (and unsurprisingly...) *BootExecute* start first then *PendingFileRenameOperations*...

In my log

BootExecute                 start at 18:43:45, **4660048**

PendingFileRenameOperations start at 18:43:45, **4861988**

[image: BootExecute]

[image: PendingFileRenameOperations]

Answer (score 1):

BootExecute will start first (most likely because it can be used to do jobs to bring the file system in order, e.g. do a checkdisk, complete partition management, etc.), without which there would be no renaming because no file system.